# Converting letters to numbers and symbols

Tags: python

Write a Python program to read a sentence from the user and print the sentence again after making the following changes:

- Convert all `a` and `A`,to `@`
- Convert `s` and `S`, to `$`
- Convert `o` and `O`, to `0`
- Convert `g` and `G`, to `8`
- Convert `i` and `I`, to `!`

This is my code:

```
#user inputs a sentence
iSent=(input("Enter a sentence that you want to convert the letters of:"))

#Process of converting the letters
print(iSent.replace("s","$"))
print(iSent.replace("S","$"))
print(iSent.replace("o","0"))
print(iSent.replace("O","0"))
print(iSent.replace("g","8"))
print(iSent.replace("G","8"))
print(iSent.replace("i","!"))
print(iSent.replace("I","!"))
```

This is my result:

```
Enter a sentence that you want to convert the letters of:
Summer season is a great season
Summer $ea$on i$ a great $ea$on    
$ummer season is a great season    
Summer seas0n is a great seas0n    
Summer season is a great season    
Summer season is a 8reat season    
Summer season is a great season    
Summer season !s a great season    
Summer season is a great season
```

how do I write this code in a way it converts the letters in 1 line and not multiple?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary to store the symbols you want to replace your letters with (and since you replace uppercase and lowercase letters by the same symbol you just need to store the value for either the upper or the lowercase):

```
letters_to_symbols = {
    'S': '$',
    'O': '0',
    'G': '8',
    'I': '!'
  }
```

and then just cycle through your dictionary:

```
isEnt = input('enter your sentence here:\n')

for letter, symbol in letters_to_symbols.items():
    isEnt = isEnt.replace(letter, symbol)
    isEnt = isEnt.replace(letter.lower(), symbol)

print(isEnt)
```

The result is:

```
enter your sentence here:
>>> Summer season is a great season

$ummer $ea$0n !$ a 8reat $ea$0n
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
>>> src = "asogi"
>>> tgt = "@$08!"
>>> text = "Summer season is a great season"
>>> text.translate(str.maketrans(src + src.upper(), tgt*2))
'$ummer $e@$0n !$ @ 8re@t $e@$0n'
```

This will replace the characters in `'asogiASOGI'` with the resp. character in `'@$08!@$08!'`.

If instead you want to replace just one character at a time, but in fewer lines, use `zip` and a loop (same output as in your question):

```
for s, t in zip(src+src.upper(), tgt*2):
    print(text.replace(s, t))
```